# Переместить объект Pygame по данным, полученным по TCP

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tcp, tcpclient

Возможно ли перемещать объект в Pygame, не нажимая клавиатуры или мышки, только по полученным  данным TCP? Допустим, пришли данные что высота объекта 5, и объект сам поднимается на эту высоту, дальше высота растет и объект поднимается на верх, согласно полученным данным

Comment: Да, так и работают многие игры. В принципе нет разницы как получены данные - от клавиатуры, из сети или прочитаны с файла.

Comment: спасибо)) можете. пожалуйста, ответить еще на один вопрос) возможно ли привязать текст к объекту. То есть, когда двигается объект текст рядом с ним был всегда?

Comment: обычно либо просто их двигают в одной функции, просто к координатам объекта добавляют необходимое смещение. Или второй вариант - объект и текстовое поле помещают в один контейнер и уже его двигают. Но я не настолько хорошо знаю pygame.

Comment: благодарю, Вас)